# how to find warn logs in map/reduce jobs?

Tags: hadoop

We log warnings in our mapper and reducer phases.  I am wondering if there is any good way to find the logs that would contain warn logs easily rather than searching through every log.  Does hadoop M/R have anything for this?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's what you ask but you could try the following command on the prompt:

```
tail -f $HADOOP_INSTALL/*tasktracker*.log $HADOOP_INSTALL/*datanode*.log | grep -i warning
```

Which will output any new line in any of the datanode or tasktracker logs files that has the word "warning" (ignoring case)

If you ask for a distributed solution you could do exactly the same throught SSH like this

```
ssh slave1 'tail -f $HADOOP_INSTALL/*tasktracker*.log $HADOOP_INSTALL/*datanode*.log | grep -i warning
```

With one line for each slave or a bash for loop

I hope it helps